# cannot open ccsm

Tags: unity, compiz, ccsm

I uninstalled compiz, compizconfig-settings-manager and unity (sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove). Moreover I removed manually (sudo rm -rf) all folders connected with compiz: compiz and compizconfig directories (also from File System). Now I installed back compiz, compizconfig-settings-manager and unity. When I want to run **ccsm** (I have to turn on unity plugin) from a terminal I get following info:

```
libcompizconfig: dlopen: usr/lib/compizconfig/backends/libini.so: cannot open shared 
object file: no such file or directory 
integration: true
profile: default
adding plugins
segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How to fix that ?

Comment: Now compiz, compizconfig-settings-manager and unity are uninstalled and I get an info: invalid operation reinstall. Should I use install ? I think that there should be compiz* instead of compix*, right ?

Comment: Oops... `install --reinstall` instead of `reinstall`, if it is not installed, just use `install`. - <rant>I hate `apt-get`, can't it have sensible options like `reinstall`, `search` *(yes, you can use `apt-cache...`)*, or something?</rant>

Comment: What does it mean compix* ?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get reinstall compiz*`- command line is better, as it shows the errors easily. I 've had to do that twice, and often I had to remove the extra `compiz*` packages, and then reinstall `compizconfig-settings-manager`, then reinstall the extra `compiz*` packages

Comment: I have already type compix* and it has started installed a lot of things, i just close terminal , what now ?

Comment: it should be fine - it seems to accept `compix*` as though it was `compiz*` :-S - so it is not only me that gets confused... You may be prompted to complete the transaction, otherwise `apt-get` won't work. If you did remove unity, you should be able to restore it with `sudo apt-get install unity ubuntu-desktop`